# Nested JSON requests in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

So trying to get two JSON requests to happen after each other, and seems like the javascript does the first request, but never even attempts the second one.

So, first one asks for colors, the second one asks for values, the code looks like this

```
(function() { 
    var mapKeyUrl = "/GenMap/getcountry/mapdata"
    $.getJSON(mapKeyUrl, {
        regsel: "${regsel}",
        variable: "mapcolor"
    })
    .done(function( coldata ) { 
        console.log( "JSON Data: " + coldata[1].value );
        (function() {
            mapKeyUrl = "/GenMap/getcountry/mapdata"
            $.getJSON(mapKeyUrl, {
                regsel: "${regsel}",
                variable: "mapkey"

            })
            .done(function( mapdata ) {
                console.log( "JSON Map:" + mapdata)
            })
        })

    });
})();
```

Both requests return valid JSON data, so mapcolor for example:

```
[{"class":"genmap.Mapconf","id":55,"map":"0","reg":"FATCA","value":"#F0F0F0","variable":"mapcolor"},{"class":"genmap.Mapconf","id":56,"map":"1","reg":"FATCA","value":"#66CCFF","variable":"mapcolor"},{"class":"genmap.Mapconf","id":57,"map":"2","reg":"FATCA","value":"#0000FF","variable":"mapcolor"},{"class":"genmap.Mapconf","id":58,"map":"3","reg":"FATCA","value":"#CC66FF","variable":"mapcolor"},{"class":"genmap.Mapconf","id":59,"map":"4","reg":"FATCA","value":"#9900CC","variable":"mapcolor"},{"class":"genmap.Mapconf","id":60,"map":"5","reg":"FATCA","value":"#7D7D7D","variable":"mapcolor"}]
```

And mapkey returns a similar list.

Any suggestions, need to run three of these, and one I have all the data I need to recombine it.

Comment: have you tried stepping through the code to see what happens?

Comment: My guess is that you end up in a `fail` callback in your first call. Try adding one

Comment: You're never calling the second function. At the end of the main function you have `})();` with the `()` to call it, but at the end of the inner function you just have `})`

Comment: The problem is that you wrap second AJAX request with anonymous function which never invoked. Just remove these wrapping lines and the code will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(function() {
    mapKeyUrl = "/GenMap/getcountry/mapdata"
    //...
})
```

You define a function but you never call it, which is why it doesn't run.

Since there is no point in wrapping it in a function anyway, just omit it:

```
.done(function( coldata ) { 
    console.log( "JSON Data: " + coldata[1].value );

    mapKeyUrl = "/GenMap/getcountry/mapdata"
    $.getJSON(mapKeyUrl, {
        regsel: "${regsel}",
        variable: "mapkey"

    }).done(function( mapdata ) {
        console.log( "JSON Map:" + mapdata)
    });

});
```

Comment: Well spotted and thank you so very much. Been swearing about JSON for a while, so thought it was another wonderful JSON special, turned out it was me forgetting to add var :)

Comment: OK, so I changed it to be a var, but that does not seem to do the trick, or am I missing the point? Still only one response

Comment: @vrghost Updated my answer. It helps to learn the basics before doing complex AJAX stuff. ;) https://developer.mozilla.org/en/learn/javascript

Comment: @jglitch: I would have loved to not need to use JSON, but needed a way to get data from the backend to the browser, and that was the only way I could find to do it:)

Answer (score 1):

please use this inside function.@jgillich  is right.you can call it like as you done in parent function.

```
(function() {
        mapKeyUrl = "/GenMap/getcountry/mapdata"
        $.getJSON(mapKeyUrl, {
            regsel: "${regsel}",
            variable: "mapkey"

        })
        .done(function( mapdata ) {
            console.log( "JSON Map:" + mapdata)
        })
    })();
```